# How do you Replace or Override the org.jboss.log4j.LogManager?

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j, wildfly

For a system I am working on, we log to a separate file during a scheduled task those messages with a higher level (but only for that file instead of using the default file that is used for all internal and external classes.)

This was previously done by using our own LoggerRepository implementation which could have a separate logging hierarchy on a specific thread if a value was set in the MDC.

However in Wildfly 8.x `org.jboss.log4j` is used instead of `org.apache.log4j`, which does not allow us to use our own LoggerRepository. When we try to use it, the application throws a security exception.

Are there any new ways in Wildfly 8.x with `org.jboss.log4j` to achieve what we are trying, or is there a way to get Wildfly to utilise the official `org.apache.log4j` rather than the jboss fork?

Comment: What is your logger configuration? Because if you are using slf4j, then you should be able to select which logger to use.

Comment: The log levels are fully configured in the domain.xml of wildfly, and we are using log4j through the library provided by wildfly.

Comment: Ok. I usually have to update my maven pom.xml and configure the dependency to exclude the unwanted logger. Then it should use my logger rather than the dependency's logger.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an option unless nothing else works, as it would split the server log into a Wildfly log and an application log.